# Omron PLC elpsed time

Tags: time, types, automation, timer, plc

I'm wokring on project with Omron PLC, I need to show on HMI elapsed time after I started my system but problem is that, I can see my time just in seconds but I need in hour and min type. How to display elapsed time in hour and minute type  from Omron Nx1 PLC to HMI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to calculate the total hours and minutes from the total secconds and display on the HMI. You could concatenate the values into a string, but since I don't know what your purpose is, it's easier to use the values directly in integers with two different variables.

As you didn't define the language, here's an example in Structured-text. The Time given in Seconds in TotalSeconds will be separated into Hours and Minutes (and also Seconds as a bonus!).

Note: I'm putting the variable declaration as text, but I know that in Sysmac it is possible to declare it as a table...

**Declaration**

```
VAR
    TotalSeconds : DINT;
    Seconds : DINT;
    Minutes : DINT;
    Hours : DINT;
    rest : DINT;
END_VAR
```

**Program**

```
rest := TotalSeconds MOD 3600;
Seconds := rest MOD 60;
Minutes := (rest - seconds) / 60;
Hours := (TotalSeconds - rest) / 3600;
```

**Example**

```
  242 s >>> 0 h /  4 min /  2 s
33868 s >>> 9 h / 24 min / 28 s
```